# git pull forced with exceptions

Tags: git, version-control, git-pull, git-reset

I want to do automatic(no manual intervention) `git pull` from git remote repository.

**But that some files are kept in local state** and all others are same as in remote repository.

I have found [How do I force "git pull" to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files)

The solution from that answer is:

> git fetch --all
>
> git reset --hard origin/master

But this is overwriting all files in the local directory to state from origin/master.

How can I do this, but with excluding some files?

More info:
I am making one deployment script (I know that fabric/git is not the best solution, but if I can do this than it is good enough for me.)

Comment: Maybe was answerd here already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216411/how-do-i-pull-files-from-remote-without-overwriting-local-files

Comment: @StefanF. thank you. By doing `git stash; git fetch; git reset --hard; git stash pop` look like it is doing what I want.

Comment: @WebOrCode You can write the commands as an answer and mark it.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT added :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use in my fabric script:

```
run('git stash') 
run('git fetch') 
run('git reset --hard origin/master') 
run('git stash pop')
```